# Free SVN for Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2015

I'm searching for a free SVN which I can use for Visual Studio 2015 Community. I founded something in older blogs about Team Foundation Server. I downloaded it, but it's only a 90 day trial version.
Are there any other tools i could use?

Many thanks to you :)

Comment: Where did you download from? Ankhsvn is released under an open source Apache license.

Comment: I'm sorry, i mean Team Foundation Server

Comment: For AnkhSVN I havn't found a tutorial which I understand.

Comment: Do you know how to use search engines such as google? Maybe you should search the web? Google `SVN for Visual Studio`.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, tough crowd of commenters here who seem to think every question should be at a level they'd ask, or it's not legit and should be voted down.  Lately I'm seeing too much "forum police" and too little "legitimate help".

To your question:

We have been using AnkhSVN for years, and now with VS 2015 CE.  It's good.

My suggestions:

Close Visual Studio.

Install AnkhSVN from https://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/

Configure Visual Studio to use the AnkhSVN plug-in, specifically, in the Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-in Selection section.

Note that there is a separate Pending Changes panel for AnkhSVN than with TeamFoundation in the View > Other Windows menu, and unfortunately they both show in the menu with the same name.  For me it's the lower one, which is listed with shortcut keys Ctrl+K, C, that serves AnknSVN.

We find AnkhSVN in VS 2015 CE works well along side TortoiseSVN, which integrates with Windows Explorer.  There are cases, e.g., for module deletions, where commits need to be done with Tortoise in order to work out right.

Comment: The problem is that these types of questions are offtopic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Right, because they have nothing at all to do with software development.  Oops, did you notice that there are Visual Studio and SVN tags?